# really long environment variable in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I was just going through this Dockerfile **[HERE](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/~/dockerfile/)** ,

what really struck me was the way an environment variable was declared , see below:

```
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1
```

the environment variable gets used like so:

```
RUN apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \ && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But why does the environment variable , have such a long name ? can somebody explain this ?

Comment: I think this question if asked to it's author can be resolved quickly, and I believe he is referencing specific commit from git.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the environment variable name is to keep the specific postgis version ID out of the RUN commands for clarity and potential re-use. It's not necessarily to make it shorter.